# Convert JSON response to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

I have the following example response provided in JSON. I'd like to be able to convert this to a C# DataTable so I can loop through the elements and program on from there.

```
{
  "totalItems" : 10,
  "pageSize" : 20,
  "page" : 1,
  "items" : [ {
    "type" : "call",
    "uri" : "http://link.com",
    "created" : "2014-07-28T10:02:48.000+0000",
    "callType" : "external",
    "from" : "01234567891",
    "to" : "01234567892",
    "callId" : "ast01-1406541749.604847",
    "links" : {
      "recordings" : "http://link.com"
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "call",
    "uri" : "http://link.com"
    "created" : "2014-07-22T15:21:02.000+0000",
    "callType" : "external",
    "from" : "01234567895",
    "to" : "01234567898",
    "callId" : "ast02-1406042397.63768",
    "links" : {
      "recordings" : "http://link.com"
    }
  } ],
  "nextPage" : "http://link.com"
}
```

I am using JSON.net. Trouble is when I go to convert to DataTable using the following:

```
DataTable items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);
```

the debugger returns..

"Unexpected JSON token while reading DataTable: StartObject"

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Why don't you simply convert the json to some concrete classes instead of DataTable? See http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: How would I then push each element into the class?

Comment: I would validate the JSON string by pasting into an online tool such as http://json.parser.online.fr/

You appear to have a missing comma after "http://link.com"

Comment: @Adam92 Let the site I linked create the classes then call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *L.B* suggested you'll need to create custom classes and deserialize the posted JSON into them instead of `DataTable`. The reason is simple: To deserialize JSON string into `DataTable` the JSON string must follow some particular format. As `DataTable` represents a collection of rows and columns your JSON string must represent a collection (javascript array). All nested objects in the JSON string also must be a part of a javascript array, because the built in `DataTableConverter` (that is used when you try to deserialize JSON to `DataTable` type) will not be able to deserialize the JSON string. The exception you get is because of the following row:

```
"links" : {
      "recordings" : "http://link.com"
    }
```

If you change it to

```
"links": [{
                "recordings": "http://link.com"
            }]
```

you'll be one step closer to deserialize it correctly to `DataTable`.

Next step is to make the whole JSON string a javascript array. Something like this:

```
[{
    "totalItems": 10,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "page": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "call",
            "uri": "http://link.com",
            "created": "2014-07-28T10:02:48.000+0000",
            "callType": "external",
            "from": "01234567891",
            "to": "01234567892",
            "callId": "ast01-1406541749.604847",
            "links": [{
                "recordings": "http://link.com"
            }]

        },
        {
            "type": "call",
            "uri": "http://link.com",
            "created": "2014-07-22T15:21:02.000+0000",
            "callType": "external",
            "from": "01234567895",
            "to": "01234567898",
            "callId": "ast02-1406042397.63768",
            "links": [{
                "recordings": "http://link.com"
            }]
        }
    ],
    "nextPage": "http://link.com"
}]
```

After this you'll be able to deserialize it to `DataTable` with the following line:

```
DataTable items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);
```

If changing the JSON string is not an option, you'll have to deserialize your JSON to custom classes as *L.B* suggested.

Comment: I have a similar problem.. If I covert Json from a file read in as a string to datatable it works fine however if I convert from a string from httpclient I get the same error as op

The data only needs to be reviewed so I don't want to create a load of concrete classes and then build viewers on top. I want to simply create a datatable and pass that to a gridview