# How to Convert Json String into DataTable in ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, json-api

I am using [this API](http://manage.directi.com/kb/answer/764). It gives json output according to user input. For Example:

```
{
"apple.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"},
"microsoft.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"apple.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"microsoft.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.org":{"status":"unknown"}
}
```

Now I want to change this json output in dataTable and then Bind in Data Control like Gridview and repeater.

I am using [this method](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-json-string-to-datatable-in-asp-net1) to do this but when I passed above json output in this method , It throws an Error

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Deserialize your jsonstring to some class
List<myCLass> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myCLas>>(jsonString); And then create new datatable using that list

Comment: Also this is faster : DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));

Comment: Sorry!! I am unable to understand . Can you write some code here in detail. bcoz I have already used this code " DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable))); "

Comment: A DataTable is a bad choice to convert it to. You're much better off creating a model that is a .NET object representing the data from your JSON. GridView and Repeater both have support for binding to anything that implements IEnumerable. This makes it much easier to work with. However, your JSON is a strange format, and the correct C# class to represent it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON response to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995875/convert-json-response-to-datatable)

Comment: I agree with you .....but I think you could not understand my question in detail bcoz I have already cleared that I have two json string in my online demo [link](http://way2seo.com/default3.aspx) ..one is working and another is not working ...It means I cannot change my json string format bcoz it is generated by user input [link](http://way2seo.com/default.aspx)...... Please help me.

Comment: @user3786581 why do I get the impression that you [asked this already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310039/how-to-read-json-response-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-reseller-club-domain-check-av) ?

Comment: @user3786581 You don't need to use a DataTable, just make it clear what you want to bind to. You *can* read the Json data and you *can* bind the parsed objects to GridViews, tables, repeaters etc, without going through a DataTable. There are various ways to bind to flat objects *and* nested objects

Answer (score 3):

To convert to `DataTable` You must understood what You are doing:

`DataTable` represents a collection of **rows** and **columns** your JSON string must represent a collection which can by convert to collection of **rows** and **columns**.

This is example of correct JSON file which can by change to `DataTable`:

```
[{
    "column1": "1788",
    "column2": "19"
},
{
    "column1": "1789",
    "column2": "24"
},
{
    "column1": "1790",
    "column2": "24"
},
{
    "column1": "1790",
    "column2": "23"
},
{
    "column1": "1790",
    "column2": "21"
}]
```

Each pair `column1` and `column2` is the row

Now Your JSON is not good. I change it to this: (correct `DataTable` schema)

```
  [{
        "name": "apple.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.com",
        "status": "available",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "apple.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    }]
```

And I add `[` sign and `]` sign at the beginning and the end of array

Next You can do this. It is working example for deserializing above JSON string to `DataTable`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonExample
    {

        private string jsonObject = "[{ \"name\": \"apple.com\",    \"status\": \"regthroughothers\",   \"classkey\": \"domcno\"},{ \"name\": \"asdfgqwx.com\", \"status\": \"available\",  \"classkey\": \"domcno\"},{ \"name\": \"microsoft.org\",    \"status\": \"unknown\",    \"classkey\": \"\"},{   \"name\": \"apple.org\",    \"status\": \"unknown\",    \"classkey\": \"\"},{   \"name\": \"microsoft.com\",    \"status\": \"regthroughothers\",   \"classkey\": \"domcno\"},{ \"name\": \"asdfgqwx.org\", \"status\": \"unknown\",    \"classkey\": \"domcno\"}]".Trim();

        public JsonExample()
        { 
            DataTable items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonObject);

            foreach (DataRow item in items.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item[0]} Status: {item[1]}  classkey {item[2]} " );
            }

        }
    }
```

**BUT** if You sill don;t want to change JSON file

```
private string jsonObject = JSON_String.Replace("{", "[{").Replace("}", "}]");

public JsonExample()
        {
            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonObject);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("status");
            dt.Columns.Add("classkey");

            foreach (JProperty item in jArray[0])
            {
                var jArray2 = JArray.Parse(item.Value.ToString());

                foreach (var item2 in jArray2)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(item.Name, item2["status"], item2["classkey"]);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name} Status: {item2["status"]}  classkey {item2["classkey"]} ");
                }
            } 
        }
```

Effect is the same as but You don't need do change the JSON String exept 2 replace.

Effect when You parse first string with method I write:

[image]

Additional information:

[Convert JSON response to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995875/convert-json-response-to-datatable)

Comment: Change how it's generated, goldeinsten is correct. The error you're getting means the json cannot parse, or even begin to start parsing because it's at line 1, pos 1. I'd say your json generation is erroneous over the actual datatable implementation.

Comment: @user3786581 ok, i see. I update my answer to do this

Comment: @goodeinstein note that this has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310039/how-to-read-json-response-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-reseller-club-domain-check-av) and the OP is actually asking how to display the data in ASP.NET. There's no need to convert the data to a DataTable at all. While BoundFields can only bind to immediate properties, a Template field can bind to nested properties, allowing you to bind to the nested `status`, `classkey` properties directly

Comment: Thanks, I see, but since yesterday I want to answer to this question the correct way and I learn much about JSON.NET and today I  discover how to use JArray object  : )

Comment: Thanks to All of you ...Specially @goodeinstein.Finally I got it.